# Leveling a road in a terrain height map

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, terrain, 3d-modelling, heightmap

Suppose we have a height map representing terrain elevation in the form of an image where each pixel indicates height. Suppose another layer on that same image is being used to indicate the path of a road across the terrain, so a bright pixel indicates a point on the road, a dark pixel indicates off the road, and intermediate pixels represent places that are along the edge of the road. That seems like a natural way to represent a road in this situation, but we could also convert it to a polygonal outline of the road using Marching Squares.

The question is: how can an algorithm adjust the height map to keep the road horizontal from side-to-side. It would be easy to make the road entirely horizontal by averaging the elevations of every point on the road, but that's not how real roads work. A road should be able to run up and down hills, but not slant left or right.

There must be some geometric solution to do with finding the angle of the road and linearly interpolating the heights between pixels. Or is there some trickier solution that gives good results in practice without working so hard at it?

Answer (score 1):

If road is defined with vector data (lines), than solution to the problem would be clearer. As Yves wrote, heights used to fill the road are heights on the road center line (axis), and values are propagated perpendicular to the axis, for half of road width on both sides. That is also quite complicate to calculate. Main problem is with bends (angles) on axis line. That is because sides and axis have different lengths on bends and care has to be taken to travel 'parallel' on these three lines.

Rasterized problem can be solved by finding pixels that are perpendicular to some point on axis. It is possible to use approach that finds set of pixels with similar property. Like taking one road side pixel and finding
shortest pixel path to other road side produces line of pixels that are (probably) perpendicular to the axis. Pixels on shortest path line can use same height, value of middle pixel or even average value.

With this kind of approach same bend problem will occur since pixels from inner road side can have more nearest pixels on outer road side. Maybe more averaging can help here. I would go with approach to find shortest path from each pixel on both sides. For each shortest line find height value to use. With that one pixel will be on more shortest lines, and it can use average value of shortest lines it is on. If some pixel is not covered with shortest line, use average value of neighbouring pixels.

I think that nodes of graph uses for finding shortest paths (constructed from road pixels) have 8 neighbours, and edges has to be weighted, where horizontal/vertical edges have weight 1 and diagonal edges have weight sqrt(2).

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate horizontal normals to the road at every point and average height points along these normals. This would help you to keep normals horizontal - and that's how actual roads behave.

Comment: Does "every point" mean the center of every pixel? Wouldn't the normal through the center of one pixel rarely pass through the center of more than one pixel? If we count the pixels that are merely touched by the normal, then many pixels would be touched by many normals, so which normal do we use to calculate the average for each pixel?

Comment: Maybe try some kind of weighted average if pixel is touched by multiple normals...

Answer (score 0):

Use the height of the pixels along the road axis and set this height on the height map along the normal to the axis. This is technically a little complicated. What you can do is to mesh the road in tiny quadrilaterals, and "fill" the quadrilaterals with constant or bilinearly interpolated heights.

For better realism, you way have to carve the terrain a little on the rising side and fill on the downward side to avoid vertical walls and respect the embankment slopes. This can be done by extending the mesh outside the road with extra quadrilaterals to which you give a slope.